# How do sfdx-cli version numbers and release notes work?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Just ran sfdx and was prompted:

```
sfdx-cli: update available from 6.24.0-9405104f19 to 6.25.0-085abe54b0
```

Great! let me just see what's changed.  A quick search for "sfdx-cli release notes" netted me [a page full of release notes](https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/releasenotes.html) but the version numbers don't bear any resemblance to the message above; the latest release in the notes is "43.8.0 (July 19, 2018)".  Next I searched "sfdx-cli 6.25.0" (from the "update available" message) and found [the npm package page for sfdx-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sfdx-cli), which is currently at 6.25.0, and was published a day ago... which clearly jives with the release date for 43.8.0 on the release notes page.  Unfortunately, the npm page doesn't include any release notes and doesn't mention any 43.xx version number.

Thinking that perhaps 6.25.0 is just an npm version number, I checked with the tool itsself:

```
> $ sfdx version                                                                           
▸    sfdx-cli: update available from 6.24.0-9405104f19 to 6.25.0-085abe54b0
```

So, is there a way to convert 6.xx version numbers to 43.xx version numbers?  Do I have the wrong version of `sfdx` installed?  Or is there a set of release notes available for the 6.xx version?  I can intuit which is which based on release dates, but I'd prefer to have a definitive set of release notes based on a matching version number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The under-the-hood architecture for the CLI can and will change as we embrace new technologies - but the corresponding API version, like v43.x, will continue to correspond to a release, in this case, Summer 18. You can run `sfdx plugins --core` to see the version you're running - and we'll continue to use that version for the CLI release notes in the foreseeable future. I'm unsure if there's any automated way to map npm version to CLI/API version.

Comment: Thanks, `sfdx plugins --core` did just show me I had salesforcedx 43.7.1, and after I ran `sfdx update`, it shows me I have salesforcedx 43.8.1 (newer than the release notes!?)  Are there release notes published anywhere for the CLI npm package?

Comment: If you want an automatic way to map (and you have jq) you can run the following: `npm view sfdx-cli --json | jq .dependencies.salesforcedx` If you want a specific version, `npm view sfdx-cli@6.24.0  --json | jq .dependencies.salesforcedx`. If you don't have jq and don't want to install it, you could just `| grep salesforcedx` instead. Also, no release notes for the CLI npm package as of now. Usually, they are just updating core plugins.